# expand a variable upon evaluation not assignment

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having trouble with some make variables, I have something like this:

```
SUFFIX := raw

FILENAME = name.$(SUFFIX)

...
...

#much later, in a different makefile far away:
SUFFIX := img

echo $(FILENAME)
```

But FILENAME has the original raw suffix value (name.raw), not the more recently assigned "img" value.

Am I missing something simple here? Using latest released gmake.

Comment: How are the two makefiles connected? Does one include the other, or call the other, or is there a third involved, or what?

Comment: Beta: I believe there is a series of includes.

Comment: The shell recipes are stored as recursive variables. Thus `echo $(FILENAME)` will give `$FILENAME` as it is at the time the recipe is executed. This is somewhat after the makefiles have been read and parsed.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this error with a series of includes; there is something else involved. I suggest you try the following and tell us the results:

```
@echo filename: $(FILENAME)
@echo origin: $(origin FILENAME)
@echo flavor: $(flavor FILENAME)
```

**EDIT:**
All right, now we know that `FILENAME` is being defined simply (i.e. with `:=`) somewhere. So try to trace the include chain, and find out where that happens. Here's a trick: put these lines in any makefile you're interested in

```
ifeq ($(flavor FILENAME),simple)
  $(warning FILENAME is simply defined)
endif
```

Comment: filename: name.raw

origin: file

flavor: simple